# Making web service with multiple ports in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a question about making web service from wsdl with multiple ports. WSDL look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions ...>
...
    <wsdl:service name="SomeService">
        <wsdl:port name="port1" binding="tns:port1">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com/port1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="port2" binding="tns:port2">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com/port2"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can see - there are two ports in one service. But after wsimport source generation, when i open my service wsdl (http://localhost/myapp/SomeService?wsdl) i see only one of these ports:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions ...>
...
    <wsdl:service name="SomeService">
        <wsdl:port name="port1" binding="tns:port1">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com/port1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make it with multiple ports?

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got the answer [there](http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/30-JAX-WS-and-Multiple-Endpoints.html) - by adding sun-jaxws.xml file to my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
<endpoint 
    name="port1" 
    implementation="my.package.port1class" 
    interface="my.package.port1interface" 
    wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdl/wsdl.xml" 
    service="{http://localhost.com/}Service" 
    port="{http://localhost.com/}port1" 
    url-pattern="/service"/>
<endpoint 
    name="port2" 
    implementation="my.package.port2class" 
    interface="my.package.port2interface" 
    wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdl/wsdl.xml" 
    service="{http://localhost.com/}Service" 
    port="{http://localhost.com/}port2" 
    url-pattern="/service"/>
</endpoints>
```